# How to communicate with different TCP clients not only with the first one connected?

Tags: c#

I have a asynchronous TCP project and I can handle multiple connections.

But,for example: 
If I have two clients connected how can I communicate with both of them?

Answer (score 2):

Well, obviously you'll need some sort of container to hold the current connections along with an internal identifier (key) that lets you find the connection you want to send something on.

If you have problems with this, please post a more specific question.